# Tensorflow - Temporal Convolutional Network not learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoregressive-models, tensorflow-probability

I developed an autoregressive Temporal Convolutional Network in Tensorflow. However, when I add a probabilistic layer in the Temporal Block, it stops learning with full batch. In mini batch, loss improves, accuracy also, but accuracy in the test set does not change.

The issue causing this is this line of code:

`x = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=.1))(x)`

The code is the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

dataframe = pd.read_csv('international-airline-passengers.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python', skipfooter=3)
dataset = dataframe.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

def norm(x):
    return (x-np.min(x))/(np.max(x)-np.min(x))

#dataset=norm(dataset)

look_back=3
np.random.seed(7)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.8)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
print(len(train), len(test))

def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=look_back):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
trainX

trainY = trainY.reshape(len(trainY), 1)
testY = testY.reshape(len(testY), 1)
trainY

X0=trainX
Y0=trainY

tfd = tfp.distributions

class TemporalConvNet(tf.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_channels, kernel_size=2, dropout=0.2,
                 trainable=True, name=None, dtype=None, 
                 activity_regularizer=None, **kwargs):
        super(TemporalConvNet, self).__init__(
            trainable=trainable, dtype=dtype,
            activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer,
            name=name, **kwargs
        )
        self.layers = []
        num_levels = len(num_channels)
        for i in range(num_levels):
            dilation_size = 2 ** i
            out_channels = num_channels[i]
            self.layers.append(
                TemporalBlock(out_channels, kernel_size, strides=1, dilation_rate=dilation_size,
                              dropout=dropout, name="tblock_{}".format(i))
            )

    def call(self, inputs, training=True):
        outputs = inputs
        for layer in self.layers:
            outputs = layer(outputs, training=training)
        return outputs

learning_rate = 0.001
display_step = 10
num_input = 10
num_hidden = 20
num_classes = 1

dropout = 0.1
kernel_size = 8
levels = 6

class CausalConv1D(tf.layers.Conv1D):
    def __init__(self, filters,
               kernel_size,
               strides=1,
               dilation_rate=1,
               activation=None,
               use_bias=True,
               kernel_initializer=None,
               bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
               kernel_regularizer=None,
               bias_regularizer=None,
               activity_regularizer=None,
               kernel_constraint=None,
               bias_constraint=None,
               trainable=True,
               name=None,
               **kwargs):
        super(CausalConv1D, self).__init__(
            filters=filters,
            kernel_size=kernel_size,
            strides=strides,
            padding='valid',
            data_format='channels_last',
            dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
            activation=activation,
            use_bias=use_bias,
            kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
            bias_initializer=bias_initializer,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
            bias_regularizer=bias_regularizer,
            activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer,
            kernel_constraint=kernel_constraint,
            bias_constraint=bias_constraint,
            trainable=trainable,
            name=name, **kwargs
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        padding = (self.kernel_size[0] - 1) * self.dilation_rate[0]
        inputs = tf.pad(inputs, tf.constant([(0, 0,), (1, 0), (0, 0)]) * padding)
        return super(CausalConv1D, self).call(inputs)


class TemporalBlock(tf.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_outputs, kernel_size, strides, dilation_rate, dropout=0.2, 
                 trainable=True, name=None, dtype=None, 
                 activity_regularizer=None, **kwargs):
        super(TemporalBlock, self).__init__(
            trainable=trainable, dtype=dtype,
            activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer,
            name=name, **kwargs
        )        
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.n_outputs = n_outputs
        self.conv1 = CausalConv1D(
            n_outputs, kernel_size, strides=strides, 
            dilation_rate=dilation_rate, activation=tf.nn.relu, 
            name="conv1")
        self.conv2 = CausalConv1D(
            n_outputs, kernel_size, strides=strides, 
            dilation_rate=dilation_rate, activation=tf.nn.relu, 
            name="conv2")
        self.down_sample = None


    def build(self, input_shape):
        channel_dim = 2
        self.dropout1 = tf.layers.Dropout(self.dropout, [tf.constant(1), tf.constant(1), tf.constant(self.n_outputs)])
        self.dropout2 = tf.layers.Dropout(self.dropout, [tf.constant(1), tf.constant(1), tf.constant(self.n_outputs)])
        if input_shape[channel_dim] != self.n_outputs:
            self.down_sample = tf.layers.Dense(self.n_outputs, activation=None)

    def call(self, inputs, training=True):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x, training=training)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x, training=training)
        x = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=.1))(x)
        if self.down_sample is not None:
            inputs = self.down_sample(inputs)
        return tf.nn.relu(x + inputs)



tf.reset_default_graph()
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    tf.set_random_seed(2)

    X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, look_back,1])
    Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes])
    is_training = tf.placeholder("bool")

    logits = tf.layers.dense(
        TemporalConvNet([num_hidden] * levels, kernel_size, dropout)(
            X, training=is_training)[:, -1, :],
        num_classes, activation=None, 
        kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()
    )
    #mm,_=tf.nn.moments(tf.nn.relu(logits),axes=[1])
    prediction=tf.nn.relu(logits)

    #prediction2 = tf.reshape(tf.cast(mm,tf.float32),[-1,1])

    loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(
        labels=Y,predictions=prediction))

    accuracy=1-tf.sqrt(loss_op)

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)


    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    print("All parameters:", np.sum([np.product([xi.value for xi in x.get_shape()]) for x in tf.global_variables()]))
    print("Trainable parameters:", np.sum([np.product([xi.value for xi in x.get_shape()]) for x in tf.trainable_variables()]))

def next_batch(num, data, labels):
    idx = np.arange(0 , len(data))
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    idx = idx[:num]
    data_shuffle = [data[ i] for i in idx]
    labels_shuffle = [labels[ i] for i in idx]
    return np.asarray(data_shuffle).astype(np.float32), np.asarray(labels_shuffle).astype(np.float32)

log_dir = "/home/rubens/Documents/Dados/"
tb_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir, graph)
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = False
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.7
best_val_acc = 0.7

training_epochs = 6000
batch_size = X0.shape[0]


X0=X0.reshape(-1,look_back,1)
testX=testX.reshape(-1,look_back,1)

with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config) as sess:
    init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init)
    for step in range(1, training_epochs+1):
        Xt, Yt = next_batch(batch_size, X0, Y0)
        batch_x, batch_y = Xt,Yt
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y, is_training: True})
        if step % display_step == 0 or step == 1:
            loss, acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy], feed_dict={
                X: batch_x, Y: batch_y, is_training: False})
            test_data = testX
            test_label = testY
            val_acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: test_data, Y: test_label, is_training: False})
            print("Step " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.4f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.4f}".format(acc) + ", Test Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.4f}".format(val_acc))
            print(acc)
            if val_acc > best_val_acc:
                best_val_acc = val_acc
                save_path = saver.save(sess, "/home/rubens/Documents/Dados/model.ckpt")
                print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
    pred00 = sess.run([prediction],feed_dict={X: test_data, is_training: False})
```

An example of the output training with full batch:

```
All parameters: 108425.0
Trainable parameters: 36141
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 93.8851, Training Accuracy= -8.6894, Test Accuracy= -7.7621
-8.689434
Step 10, Minibatch Loss= 0.1591, Training Accuracy= 0.6011, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6011038
Step 20, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 30, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 40, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 50, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 60, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 70, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 80, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 90, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 100, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 110, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 120, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 130, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 140, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 150, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 160, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 170, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 180, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 190, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
Step 200, Minibatch Loss= 0.1023, Training Accuracy= 0.6801, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6800898
```

An example of the output training with mini batch:

```
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 97.8395, Training Accuracy= -8.8914, Test Accuracy= -7.7148
-8.891384
Step 10, Minibatch Loss= 0.0639, Training Accuracy= 0.7473, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.747253
Step 20, Minibatch Loss= 0.0798, Training Accuracy= 0.7175, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.71748877
Step 30, Minibatch Loss= 0.1120, Training Accuracy= 0.6653, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.66534567
Step 40, Minibatch Loss= 0.0831, Training Accuracy= 0.7117, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.7116946
Step 50, Minibatch Loss= 0.1119, Training Accuracy= 0.6654, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.66541755
Step 60, Minibatch Loss= 0.0758, Training Accuracy= 0.7246, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.72463006
Step 70, Minibatch Loss= 0.1035, Training Accuracy= 0.6783, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.67830944
Step 80, Minibatch Loss= 0.1674, Training Accuracy= 0.5908, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.59082925
Step 90, Minibatch Loss= 0.0709, Training Accuracy= 0.7337, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.7337192
Step 100, Minibatch Loss= 0.1566, Training Accuracy= 0.6043, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.60427284
Step 110, Minibatch Loss= 0.0794, Training Accuracy= 0.7182, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.7182363
Step 120, Minibatch Loss= 0.1337, Training Accuracy= 0.6343, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6343092
Step 130, Minibatch Loss= 0.0848, Training Accuracy= 0.7088, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.7087995
Step 140, Minibatch Loss= 0.0781, Training Accuracy= 0.7205, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.7205193
Step 150, Minibatch Loss= 0.1320, Training Accuracy= 0.6366, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.63664067
Step 160, Minibatch Loss= 0.1360, Training Accuracy= 0.6313, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.63125527
Step 170, Minibatch Loss= 0.0663, Training Accuracy= 0.7424, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.74244356
Step 180, Minibatch Loss= 0.1445, Training Accuracy= 0.6199, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6198952
Step 190, Minibatch Loss= 0.1157, Training Accuracy= 0.6598, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.65980613
Step 200, Minibatch Loss= 0.0960, Training Accuracy= 0.6902, Test Accuracy= 0.3290
0.6902418
```

I added normalization, decreased learning rate (as it seems to exist a plateau in the gradient), changed batch size, activation functions, hidden layers without success.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Data is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RLknmL54khVVFnUGdlclYtTmM/view?usp=sharing)

I'm using Tensorflow 1.14

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my question.

The problem was not really `x = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=.1))(x)` but the residual input that was added to the output of the Temporal Block:

Original code:

```
def call(self, inputs, training=True):
    x = self.conv1(inputs)
    x = tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(x)
    x = self.dropout1(x, training=training)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(x)
    x = self.dropout2(x, training=training)
    x = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1))(x)
    if self.down_sample is not None:
        inputs = self.down_sample(inputs)
    return tf.nn.relu(x+inputs)  ## this line
```

Solution:

```
def call(self, inputs, training=True):
    x = self.conv1(inputs)
    x = tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(x)
    x = self.dropout1(x, training=training)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(x)
    x = self.dropout2(x, training=training)
    x = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1))(x)
    if self.down_sample is not None:
        inputs = self.down_sample(inputs)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)
```

Output of training now:

```
Step 3640, Minibatch Loss= 0.0111, Training Accuracy= 0.8946, Test Accuracy= 0.7140
0.8946085
Step 3650, Minibatch Loss= 0.0110, Training Accuracy= 0.8950, Test Accuracy= 0.7313
0.8950086
Step 3660, Minibatch Loss= 0.0125, Training Accuracy= 0.8881, Test Accuracy= 0.7238
0.8880914
Step 3670, Minibatch Loss= 0.0097, Training Accuracy= 0.9013, Test Accuracy= 0.7130
0.90127575
Step 3680, Minibatch Loss= 0.0118, Training Accuracy= 0.8912, Test Accuracy= 0.7081
0.89116585
Step 3690, Minibatch Loss= 0.0132, Training Accuracy= 0.8852, Test Accuracy= 0.7126
0.8852357
Step 3700, Minibatch Loss= 0.0128, Training Accuracy= 0.8868, Test Accuracy= 0.7139
0.88682896
Step 3710, Minibatch Loss= 0.0108, Training Accuracy= 0.8960, Test Accuracy= 0.7060
0.8959798
Step 3720, Minibatch Loss= 0.0111, Training Accuracy= 0.8949, Test Accuracy= 0.7172
0.89486927
Step 3730, Minibatch Loss= 0.0116, Training Accuracy= 0.8923, Test Accuracy= 0.7342
0.8923229
Step 3740, Minibatch Loss= 0.0123, Training Accuracy= 0.8892, Test Accuracy= 0.7103
0.8891851
```